# Redirection to facebook page

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, redirect

Well, my website can not redirect to 
https://www.facebook.com/QuaFootSpa

from

http://quafootspa.com/

I have tried redirection to facebook page through 
a tag href attribute and also javascript function. but it redirects to middle page. kindly browse http://quafootspa.com/ and click on facebook icon on the top so it will redirect to middle page that says Go To Facebook.com

Clicking on the (Go to Facebook.com) will direct to https://www.facebook.com/QuaFootSpa

Comment: What's the code for the first redirect? MAybe try to link without https and use http instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `target='_top'` in the href.

So it becomes

```
<a target='_top' href="https://www.facebook.com/QuaFootSpa/">
```

Right now the link is being opened in the lower frame and FB doesnt like it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href='http://www.facebook.com/QuaFootSpa/' target='_blank'>Facebook Page</a>`
your putted `https://` instead of `http://`

Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using frame and in frame self works in the frame so use `target="_top"`

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/QuaFootSpa/" target="_top"><img src="images/qspa/fb_btn.png"></a>`